# Press F5 to save, compile, and run current rust file

Tags: elisp, key-bindings, compilation

Similar to Visual Studio, when working with Rust programs, I'd like to press *F5* to save the current file, compile it, and run it.

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Below is one approach for Windows. If you're in a rust project, it'll run `cargo run`. Otherwise, it'll use `rustc`.

```
(defun rust-save-compile-and-run ()
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)

  (if (locate-dominating-file (buffer-file-name) "Cargo.toml")

      (compile "cargo run")

    (compile
     (format "rustc %s & %s"
         (buffer-file-name)
         (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))))))

(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (define-key rust-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") 'rust-save-compile-and-run)))
```

Comment: How much harder would it be to make this work with cargo projects with multiple bins? I think it can be done by invoking just `cargo` once [this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/702) PR is merged.

Comment: How does `locate-dominating-file` work here?  Does it scan all parent directories to the file you're in to check for `Cargo.toml`?

Answer (score 5):

Here my version of `compile`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda ()
                               (interactive)
                               (save-buffer)
                               (setq-local compilation-read-command nil)
                               (call-interactively 'compile)))
```

Basically it reuses previously executed `compile` command; if you supply with a prefix argument, you are prompted for a new `compile` command for future reuse.